# Javascript var.className do not quite understand it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am reading JavaScript_and_JQuery_Interactive_Front-End_Web_Development_by_Jon_Duckett, as part of Javascript learning.
I am at page 119, adding and removing properties from object. Bellow are the html, js and css files.

I have changed javascript file

```
elPool.className = "Pool: " + hotel.pool;
```

was:

```
elPool.className = hotel.pool
```

but it doesn't seem to change output in Firefox.

Questions:

1. I had to do some thinking to understand the `.className` thing, and my conclussion is this: `var elPool` first gets the HTML value of 'pool' element (in this case it's the word 'pool'). And then that element is, through the `elPool` variable, assigned a new class (because it doesn't have it before). In this case it is a class `.true`.
   CORRECT or FALSE conclusion?
2. In CSS file there is only one joint picture for `.true` and `.false` classes. How is that possible when there has to be a cross sign and a cross-check sign, and that are two pictures?
3. `var elGym` gets a `className` `false` (through `elGym.className = hotel.gym;`),and accordingly gets CSS adjustion. How is it possible that `var elPool` gets `className` `true` when it has two things added as classNames (`"Pool: "` and `hotel.pool`)? Is the `"Pool: "` part totally ignored, or what is actually the principle here?
   Thanx all!

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JavaScript &amp; jQuery - Chapter 3: Functions, Methods &amp; Objects - Adding properties</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/c03.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>TravelWorthy</h1>
    <div id="info">
      <h2>hotel facilities</h2>
      <div id="hotelName"></div>
      <div>
        <p id="pool">Pool</p>
        <p id="gym">Gym</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/adding-and-removing-properties.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
// Set up the object
var hotel = {
  name : 'Park',
  rooms : 120,
  booked : 77
};

hotel.gym = false;
hotel.pool = true;
delete hotel.booked;

// Update the HTML
var elName = document.getElementById('hotelName'); // Get element
elName.textContent = hotel.name;                   // Update HTML with property of the object

var elPool = document.getElementById('pool');      // Get element
elPool.className = "Pool: " + hotel.pool;                     // Update HTML with property of the object

var elGym = document.getElementById('gym');        // Get element
elGym.className = hotel.gym;                       // Update HTML with property of the object
```

**CSS:**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  background: url("../images/travelworthy-backdrop.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;}

h1 {
  background: #1e1b1e url("../images/travelworthy-logo.gif") no-repeat;
  width: 230px;
  height: 180px;
  float: left;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;}

h2 {
  margin: 1.75em 0 0 0;
  color: #adffda; 
  font-weight: normal;}

h2 + p {
  margin: 0.25em 0 0 0;}
p + p {
  margin: 0;}
p + h2 {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;}

/* message under the logo */

#message {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  background-color: #ffb87a;
  color: #1e1b1e;
  width:170px;
  padding: 18px 30px;
  text-align: center;}

/* black bar across the right hand side of the page */

#info {
  background-color: #1e1b1e;
  color: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 15%;}

/* details in the black bar */

#hotelName {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center; 
  font-size: 120%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; 
  padding: 10px 0;}

#hotel1 {
  margin-top: 1em; 
  border-top: 1px solid #fff; 
  padding-top: 1em;} 
#hotel2 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; 
  padding-bottom: 1em;}

#rooms {
  font-size: 440%;
  color: #ffb87a;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;}

#roomRate{
  text-decoration: line-through;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;}

#specialRate {  
  font-size: 440%;
  color: #ffb87a;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 0 20px 0;
  margin: 0;}

#offerEnds {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffb87a;
  font-size: 75%;}

.true, .false {
  padding: 0 50px 0 50px;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-align: left;
  background-image: url("../images/check-cross.png");
  background-position: 120px 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;}

.false {
  background-position: 120px -28px;}

/* footer */

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #adffda;}

#footer p {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;}

.data {
  padding: 10px;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `document.getElementById('pool')` returns the DOM element, not its text contents. So when you assign to the `.className` property, you're setting the class of the element, as if it had `class="Pool: true"` in the HTML.
2. There's a joint entry in the CSS for `.true` and `.false`, but there's also another entry for `.false` that overrides the `background-position` style. It's using a [CSS sprite](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/): a single image file that contains several pictures at different positions, and the `background-position` arranges for the appropriate picture to appear depending on the class.
3. The `className` is a space-separated list of classes, so `"Pool: true"` is two classes, `Pool:` and `true`. Since there's no CSS for `.Pool:` (it would have to be written as `.Pool\:` because `:` has special meaning in CSS selectors), that class is effectively ignored. I'm not sure why that's in the book, maybe it's an attempt to make the meaning of the classes more obvious in the HTML. IMHO, it would be better to use classes like `pool-true` and `pool-false` or `pool` and `nopool`.

Comment: I think you kind of people only could answer these like big questions ;)

Comment: Just to add some clarifications: for #2, the single background image that contains the check and the cross is called a _CSS sprite_, you can read more about it here: https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

For #3, the reason why 'Pool: ' is ignored is that it's an invalid class name.

Comment: @Dan Although the colon is invalid in a CSS class selector (it's used as the delimiter before a pseudo-class), I don't think HTML has the same restrictions.

Comment: You're right! I guess I learned something today as well :) Thanks! https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes

Comment: Thanx Barmar for Your quick, thorough and useful answer! I am new to StackOverflow so I accidently clicked that answer was not useful, but after I clicked a few more times that it helped me.